# Session cookie custom path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I have an spring boot application and want to deploy it to wildfly12. What I'm trying to achieve is that to set a custom path for JSESSIONID cookie. But after all, my efforts haven't had any results.

I have tried to use this property in my application.properties file:

`server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/`

When I run the application with the embedded tomcat, everything works fine; But when I deploy my app to wildfly, regardless of the value of that property, it always sets the cookie path to the "context-path" of the application.

I have also tried to use this property also:

`server.servlet.context-path=/`

but no success so far!

There is also this tag inside the standalone.xml file:

`<session-cookie http-only="true" secure="true"/>`

but it seems that it has nothing to do with the cookie path, as it doesn't have any property regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you are doing is for the embedded server of spring boot application.

Embedded server settings present in application properties (can be check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) the section **# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION** and the namespace server.servlet.session.cookie.*).

To modify cookie related configuration on external servers, you have to create `CookieSerializer` bean which can be used to customize cookie configuration. e.g.

```
        @Bean
        public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
                DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
                serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); 
                serializer.setCookiePath("/"); 
                serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$"); 
                return serializer;
        }
```

You can refer [spring guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/custom-cookie.html) for more information.

Comment: how do I set the cookie value. I used Cookie class - Cookie cookie = new Cookie("mycookie", "abc"); How do I set the abc value using CookieSerializer ?

Comment: This is for customizing cookie behaviour in spring boot. You have to share more information for usecase

Comment: For simple scenario, you can add cookie in response from http mapping methods by using response.addCookie(cookiename);